# Objective-C Exponential Function

Tags: objective-c

I have this format in Microsoft Excel

Obviously the column/row will be replaced with variables, but how do I create an Exponential Algorithm in Objective C? I've been struggling with this for a while and have tried many alternatives but cannot achieve it.

Is anyone capable of answering whilst giving me an introduction to this?

Thanks in advance.

gives me a completely different result to excel

Found the source to my problem, the exponential function was partly using the formula I presented, this is where I went wrong and was trying the exp the eventual value. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why did you remove the code?  Put it back so that the question makes sense, and move that solution into a self-answer.

Comment: I removed the question because it involved a formula devised by myself to give a result to something worth value. I couldn't share the formula until the question was completed. But it basically used an exponential function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just use the standard C math library? Quoting from `man exp`:

```
EXP(3)                   BSD Library Functions Manual                   EXP(3)

NAME
     exp, exp2, expm1 -- exponential functions

SYNOPSIS

 #include <math.h>

 float
 expf(float x);

 double
 exp(double x);

 long double
 expl(long double x);

 float
 exp2f(float x);

 double
 exp2(double x);

 long double
 exp2l(long double x);

 float
 expm1f(float x);

 double
 expm1(double x);

 long double
 expm1l(long double x);

 float
 __exp10f(float x);

 double
 __exp10(double x);

DESCRIPTION
 The exp() function computes e**x, the base-e exponential of x.

 The exp2() function computes 2**x, the base-2 exponential of x.

...
```

Comment: I've tried using the exponential function but I guess I wasn't clear in my question, for example in excel I end up with 5.24 in objective c I end up with pretty much that to the nearest quadrillionth, I cannot figure out how to return the same value as excel is

Comment: for example excel exponential of 0.28063 = 0.908009 whereas objective c is giving me 1.323964